# Extracting Characters in SQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the best way of `extracting the values from vvv.www.xxx.yyy.zzz`

**Note that vvv or www or xxx or yyy or zzz can vary** i.e. it can be of any length.

For this reason I cannot use `substring with charindex`.

I don't want to do this with LOOP or CURSOR . By using CTE and a number table also it can be done but that will be a bit lengthy program.

Any simple 1 line program is there for accomplishing the same.

The desired output will be

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5

vvv  www  xxx   yyy   zzz
```

It is our assignment

Thanks

Comment: The best solution is to not store data that way. If each chunk means something differnt and you want to be able to use those chunks of data, then store them in separate fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use SUBSTRING with CHARINDEX, it just takes a bit more work:

```
declare @s as varchar(25)
set @s = 'vvv.www.xxx.yyy.zzz'
select 
left(@s, charindex('.', @s) - 1) as col1,
substring(@s, charindex('.', @s) + 1, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) - charindex('.', @s) - 1) as col2,
substring(@s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) - charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) - 1) as col3,
substring(@s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) + 1, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) + 1) - charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) - 1) as col4, 
right(@s, len(@s) - charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) + 1)) as col5
```

You could clean it up with a join like this:

```
declare @s as varchar(25)
set @s = 'vvv.www.xxx.yyy.zzz'
select left(@s, first - 1) as col1,
    substring(@s, first + 1, second - first - 1) as col2,
    substring(@s, second + 1, third - second - 1) as col3,
    substring(@s, third + 1, fourth - third - 1) as col4,
    right(@s, len(@s) - fourth)
from (select @s s) a
inner join
(
    select charindex('.', @s) as first,
    charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) as second,
    charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) as third,
    charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) + 1) + 1) as fourth
) b on 1=1
```

---

Comment: Both the queries failed in this case set @s = 'vv55v.w6666ww.xx7777x.yy88888y.z99999zz'

Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Just declare @s as a bigger varchar, it is getting truncated. I assume you would be selecting from a table anyway, that is just sample code.